# lowering minSdkVersion -- need warning messages

Tags: android, build, sdk, gradle, version

Newbie with new Android Studio project about ready for release to beta testers. I started with minSdkVersion set at 19. Now, I'd like to lower that.

So, I've lowered the minSdkVersion in the App's build.gradle file. I've used Clean, and rebuilt. It syncs and runs on my newer device. But, there are no warnings! Even if I set minSdkVersion to, say, 8. I know I've used features not supported by some older SDKs. I know from other testing, that, when you try to use features not supported by the minSdkVersion that was initally set, warning messages pop up. I need those messages now, to know what to recode.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android Studio, you can use Analyze > Inspect Code... to run an analysis of your whole project, including Lint checks. Try that and see if it gives you the results that you are seeking.

Comment: Hah, I hadn't checked out much of the Studio menu. Thanks for that. I've already worked down a couple of SDKs, and will try for more.